# ORACLE SQL COUNT QUERY - Add column into report to sum number of times the site_code appears

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum, subquery

I have a table that shows me the amount of times a job has occured at a particular site.
What I want to do is add a column within the report that shows the total number of times each site is present.

I'm using Oracle SQL 11.

```
job_entry_date       job_committed   site_code  site_name
04/04/2019 08:19    Committed   2552    COALPORT ROAD 
04/04/2019 09:07    Committed   2552    COALPORT ROAD 
04/04/2019 12:38    Committed   2621    LEES FARM DRIVE
31/03/2019 11:03    Committed   2686    HILLS LANE DRIVE
03/04/2019 11:01    Committed   2739    HALESFIELD 1
02/04/2019 11:02    Committed   2747    LEGGES WAY
04/04/2019 12:22    Committed   2751    LEES FARM ROUNDABOUT
02/04/2019 09:43    Committed   2919    DOSELEY ROAD (SPRINGHILL ROAD)
03/04/2019 17:25    Committed   2926    FOX FIELDS
03/04/2019 11:25    Committed   2944    DAWLEY POOLS AND PIT MOUND
03/04/2019 11:41    Committed   3020    DAWLEY BANK
02/04/2019 10:06    Committed   3135    PLIMMERS LANE
01/04/2019 13:44    Committed   3212    STIRCHLEY AVENUE
02/04/2019 09:31    Committed   3244    WITHYBROOK
02/04/2019 09:54    Committed   3277    BRIARWOOD
03/04/2019 11:37    Committed   3277    BRIARWOOD
01/04/2019 14:13    Committed   3281    BURFORD
03/04/2019 10:52    Committed   3281    BURFORD
03/04/2019 17:06    Committed   3281    BURFORD
04/04/2019 13:05    Committed   3281    BURFORD
03/04/2019 11:36    Committed   3387    BOULTON GRANGE
03/04/2019 11:38    Committed   3387    BOULTON GRANGE
03/04/2019 10:48    Committed   3411    ST DAVIDS CLOSE
04/04/2019 10:26    Committed   35  BRATTON ROAD
01/04/2019 10:44    Committed   3500    PURBECK DALE
03/04/2019 11:45    Committed   3500    PURBECK DALE
```

What I would like to end up with is:

```
job_number  job_entry_date  job_committed   site_code   site_name   COUNT_SITE
41000269    04/04/2019 08:19    Committed   2552    COALPORT ROAD (THE LLOYDS TO LABURNUM DR    2
41000271    04/04/2019 09:07    Committed   2552    COALPORT ROAD (THE LLOYDS TO LABURNUM DR    2
41000290    04/04/2019 12:38    Committed   2621    LEES FARM DRIVE 1
41000046    31/03/2019 11:03    Committed   2686    HILLS LANE DRIVE    1
41000206    03/04/2019 11:01    Committed   2739    HALESFIELD 1    1
41000151    02/04/2019 11:02    Committed   2747    LEGGES WAY  1
41000289    04/04/2019 12:22    Committed   2751    LEES FARM ROUNDABOUT    1
41000133    02/04/2019 09:43    Committed   2919    DOSELEY ROAD (SPRINGHILL ROAD JUNCTION H    1
41000256    03/04/2019 17:25    Committed   2926    FOX FIELDS  1
41000216    03/04/2019 11:25    Committed   2944    DAWLEY POOLS AND PIT MOUND  1
41000222    03/04/2019 11:41    Committed   3020    DAWLEY BANK 1
41000140    02/04/2019 10:06    Committed   3135    PLIMMERS LANE   1
41000101    01/04/2019 13:44    Committed   3212    STIRCHLEY AVENUE    1
41000128    02/04/2019 09:31    Committed   3244    WITHYBROOK  1
41000137    02/04/2019 09:54    Committed   3277    BRIARWOOD   2
41000220    03/04/2019 11:37    Committed   3277    BRIARWOOD   2
41000108    01/04/2019 14:13    Committed   3281    BURFORD 4
41000200    03/04/2019 10:52    Committed   3281    BURFORD 4
41000255    03/04/2019 17:06    Committed   3281    BURFORD 4
41000295    04/04/2019 13:05    Committed   3281    BURFORD 4
41000219    03/04/2019 11:36    Committed   3387    BOULTON GRANGE  2
41000221    03/04/2019 11:38    Committed   3387    BOULTON GRANGE  2
41000197    03/04/2019 10:48    Committed   3411    ST DAVIDS CLOSE 1
41000275    04/04/2019 10:26    Committed   35  BRATTON ROAD    1
41000075    01/04/2019 10:44    Committed   3500    PURBECK DALE    2
41000224    03/04/2019 11:45    Committed   3500    PURBECK DALE    2
```

How do I go about adding a new row on the of a SQL query to bring back the count of a column in Oracle 11?

Answer (score 0):

You want an analytic function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by site_id) as count_side
from t;
```